# how resolve many forms in unity dependency with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-container

In my Program.Main method, I create the container, register the service and then I resolve the main form and run it like this:

```html
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
            section.Containers.Default.Configure(container);
            container.RegisterType<IDepartementRepository, DepartementRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IDepartementService, DepartementService>();
            container.RegisterType<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<IStudentService, StudentService>();
           
           
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = container.Resolve<FrmMain>();
```

My problem is when the user clicks on a button which opens a new window and that window needs a controller, which itself needs to resolve several services? 
how can resolve many forms?

Comment: What class is the `new window`? What class is the `controller`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to create a new winforms form2 .For example : Form2 frm2 = new Form2(_studentService) .